# iOS UnitTests: Can't link to symbols in my Application target. Whats wrong?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, unit-testing

SETUP:
Xcode 4.5.2 (4G2008a)
OS X 10.7.5

---

I have an Xcode project with a normal iOS `Application` target. I am trying to add an `ApplicationTests` unit test bundle (NOT a `LogicTests` bundle) as [described by Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH3-SW1).

I have carefully followed the steps provided in the documentation, and re-checked everything a few times. However, I cannot build the ApplicationTests target... it fails with a Linker error when trying to link to one of my Appliation's classes. It seems as if setting the `Bundle Loader` build setting of the `ApplicationTests` target didn't work. But AFAICT, I have set this up correctly, as described by Apple's docs.

---

MY STEPS TO REPRO:

1. Follow [Apple's documentation for setting up an ApplicationTests bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH3-SW1).
2. Write a unit test method in the `ApplicationTests` target which imports and exercises a class from the `Application` target (e.g. `MyAppClass`).
3. Select the Application Target in the Scheme popup, and iPhone 6.0 simulator in the run destination popup
4. `Product` > `Test`

EXPECTED:
Simulator should launch and my `ApplicationTests` should run.

ACTUAL:
The `ApplicationTests` target fails to build with following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyAppClass", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ApplicationTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

If I remove references to `MyAppClass` in the unit test, the `ApplicationTests` bundle will build and run successfully.

Again, it seems like I haven't setup the `Bundle Loader` build setting properly in my `ApplicationTests` target, but I've re-checked, and I seem to have followed Apple's instructions correctly.

What could I have done wrong to make my `ApplicationTests` target not be able to link to symbols in my `Application` target?

---

**Update**: I have also tried to create new dummy projects from scratch with an `Application` and `ApplicationTests` targets. In the dummy projects, I add a `MyAppClass` class to the `Application` target, and am able to link to it and successfully run unit tests which use the `MyAppClass` in the dummy `ApplicationTests` target.

So Application Tests in my dummy projects work. But they don't work in my real project. I've compared the Targets in the dummy and real projects and cannot find a significant difference which would cause this problem for my real project only.

My real project is quite old (but also very complex, so it would be very difficult to start over). I wonder if the old-ness of the project is preventing this relatively new feature from working?

It still seems to me like I have a build settings problem in one of the targets in my real project. But I can't find it.

Comment: Is MyAppClass compiled also for the ApplicationTests target?

Comment: @Moxy, actually, no. `MyAppClass` is not selected as a file to compile into the ApplicationTests target. But it should not have to be when using creating an "Application Test" target (vs. a "Logic Tests" target) as described by Apple's documentation. (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH3-SW1)

Comment: Can you verify in the build log that when you "Build for Testing" that the -bundle_loader flag is correctly passed? Did you add the application target as a dependency of the test target?

Comment: Have you ever fixed this, Todd?

Comment: @ToddDitchendorf, by any chance, in this instance was your main target building a `static library` ?

Comment: OP here. My original target was an app target, not a static library. Unfortunately, I no longer have access to this project, so I cannot help test possible solutions. I asked this question over a year ago, and after never finding a solution, I moved on.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611988/unit-testing-in-with-a-static-library -- see answer by `quellish`.

Comment: @ToddDitchendorf, if you don't have access to the original project anymore, it doesn't sound like this question will be solvable. I opened a bounty on this question because I thought it was related to the issue I was having (same exact error message). However, it appears our setup was slightly different (my main target is creating a static library). Hopefully, if someone wanders across this question in the future, the links I've added will help them if they were in the same situation as me. Thanks for your responses to help clarify the differences. :D

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to open the project with Xcode 5.0? Select the unit test target in the project/target settings, open the "General" tab and check if the selected "Target" is your main app target.

That's where Xcode get's the information what to link to the unit test bundle loader.

Comment: Yep, `MyAppTests` > `General` > `Target` set as `MyAppProject`.

Comment: BTW, not sure if significant or not, but my main `app target` is actually a `static library` target. The OPP didn't specify, but I will ask to see if it was the same here too.

Answer (score 2):

Related Question:  [Unit Testing in With A Static Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611988/unit-testing-in-with-a-static-library)

In summary, regardless of using SenTest or XCTest, you need to make sure that

- Your main project is set as a dependency of your test target
- If your main target is a static library, your main target's library product needs to be included in your test target's `link with binary libraries` build phases

Missing either (or both) of these can result in this error.

Comment: OP here. My project meets your first criterion (I set up my test target correctly according to Apple's instructions). As for your second criterion: my main target is not a static library. As explained above, it is an *App*.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like our setup was a bit different. Hopefully, if someone finds this question in future and has a similar setup as I did, this might help them. Sorry it didn't address your issues though. :/